# Changing coordinate system says that geotransformation is invalid?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system

I am planning on using the MODIS burned area products which were produced by Maryland University. These come as either polygons or rasters. In the user guide  it says

> A shapefile version of the MCD45 product is derived from the monthly Geotiff version by the  University  of  Maryland.  The shapefiles  are  available  with  the  same  projection (Plate-Carrée) and geographic extent as the Geotiff sub-continental windows

The rest of my data are rasters (WGS 1984 UTM ZONE 38N).

When I load the MODIS fire monthly rasters into ArcGIS it says that the system coordinate system is different.

However, when I tried change the coordinate system the results output say that the geotransformation are invalid.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the data's coordinate reference system (CRS) includes a sphere-based datum. ArcGIS doesn't have any transformations to/from a sphere, thus the invalid error.

Load the raster into ArcMap with your other data, set DF to 32638 (UTM 38N). Ignore any warnings.

Does it line up? If it does, export the MODIS data by right-clicking the layer name and select data, export data. Use the data frame's coordinate system in the Export dialog.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: I did this in R. However I am worried that the projection isn't correct. Thoughts?                                                                                                                                                                                                        projection(fire) <- projection(dem)
r <- setExtent(fire, extent(dem), keepres=F)
s <- resample(r, dem, method='bilinear')
fire1<-mask(s, dem )
plot(fire1)

Comment: @I.Stirs I'm afraid that I'm not familiar with R. Maybe do a new question, linking to this one, but focusing on the R workflow?